# Using {set; get;} instead of {get; set;}

Tags: c#, oop, properties

In C# and its cousin languages, we always use

```
public string SomeString { get; set;}
```

But you can also use ( I found this out only recently and while fooling around with the compiler )

```
public string SomeString { set; get; }
```

I do not have any formal training in programming and everything is self-tought. I have been using `{ get; set; }` without any thought just like we use `1 + 1 = 2` Is the order of `{ get; set; }` just a convention or is it necessary to maintain this order or is it some remnant of a bygone era of C history like the way we define conventional electric current flowing from positive to the negative terminal when it is actually the other way around?

Comment: Fix your second code sample; you've skipped the variable name.

Comment: @Dariusz Wouldn't it have been easier to edit the question, rather than post a comment requesting the OP edit it?

Comment: @DavidArno the community frowns upon editing code in questions. Search the meta. While this is a fairly obvious case, I wasn't 101% certain it wasn't an error.

Comment: @Dariusz, Thanks, I didn't know that. I've been naively editing bad indentation and obvious typos unrelated to the question. I'd best stop though if that's the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @DavidArno I don't say I think what you did is wrong. I just don't like to take chances. If it was an answer, I would've edited the code too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no difference.**

It is exactly as if you had implemented the getter first in your class body, and the setter after it. The functions would still do exactly the same:

```
public String getSomeString() { return someString; }
public void setSomeString(String value) { someString=value; }
```

Whether they are written in that order

```
public void setSomeString(String value) { someString=value; }
public String getSomeString() { return someString; }
```

or the opposite. Wouldn't they?

I would however suggest to **stick to one order** in your code. Less entropy is always better :)

Answer (score 9):

It is purely a convention. It makes no difference which order they appear in.

Comment: This is on par with what order you overload `ToString()` or `GetHashCode()`. Property accessors are just shortcuts to `get_varname`/`set_varname` methods.

Comment: Be careful with the "are just shortcuts to" claim. I can't write a method get_X() and then reference it as X. The concept of properties exists in the CLR and thus X becomes get_X() with "I'm a property" metadata.

Comment: My apologies. I wasnt inferring there's a direct correlation,  just insight in to behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

According to the C# Language Specification http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx, 10.7.2 Accessors (page 324)

> The accessor-declarations of a property specify the executable
> statements associated with reading and writing that property.
>
> accessor-declarations:
>
> ```
> get-accessor-declaration   set-accessor-declaration
> set-accessor-declaration   get-accessor-declaration
> ```

As shown it states either order has the same effect

Answer (score 2):

[Internally Get and Set are methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) like this

```
private PropertyType Get() {}
private Set(value as PropertyType) {}
```

Since order of declaration of methods is not important, same case goes here.

MSDN:

> The body of the get accessor is similar to that of a method. It must return a value of the property type.

---

> The set accessor is similar to a method that returns void. It uses an implicit parameter called value, whose type is the type of the property.

Answer (score 1):

`{ get; set; }` is just a shortcut so you don't have to write getters and setters for every field you want to expose. It's the same as when you write

```
public string GetSomeString() { }
public void SetSomeString(string value) { }
```

Does it matter, which one you write first? Of course not.

Answer (score 1):

Just a convention you can use any of these when defining parameters:

```
public string SomeString { get; set; }
public string SomeString2 { set; get; }
    
public string someString2;

public string SomeString21
{
    get { return someString2; }
    set { someString2 = value; }
}

public string SomeString22
{
    set { someString2 = value; }
    get { return someString2; }
}

public string SomeString23
{
    set { someString2 = value; }
}

public string SomeString24
{
    get { return someString2; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, there is no difference and it is just a convention. But to prove that up, you can see how compiler actually treats your code, given the following:

```
public class C 
{
    public string SomeString { get; set;}
    public string SomeString2 { set; get; }
}
```

This will be treated as:

```
public class C
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private string <SomeString>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private string <SomeString2>k__BackingField;

    public string SomeString
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <SomeString>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <SomeString>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    public string SomeString2
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <SomeString2>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <SomeString2>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, in both of them a new `BackingField` is generated by compiler and the body of two properties are same exactly.

The [reference](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZRwAM6AygPYC2AplQC4BOAlgHYDm+63DZgG50AZ0FCAvoWJpMFavSZsu3GH3HD+E9NKSSgA===).